# Why can't cache miss degrade performance as expected?

Tags: performance, caching, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I knew that cache miss will degrade program's performance, but I wondered how much it the influence is. So I did the following experiment and the result got me confused.

I used parsec benchmark as tested program, using its runtime as a performance indicator. I ran it solo as a baseline, then I ioslated the LLC space with Intel RDT so that the program could only use three cache ways and ran it again. It turned out that there is no difference between two results. But I saw lots of cache miss happened during the second time.

Please give me some reasonable explanation of this, thanks a lot!

Comment: If most of those misses are the result of HW prefetch (into L2), that can be sufficient to hide the extra latency of having to go to DRAM instead of L3.  So the actual demand load sees an L2 hit, or still not too much latency for OoO exec to hide.  Or just that OoO exec (and hyperthreading if multithreaded) are doing their job to hide latency sufficiently for the occasional accesses that miss in L2.  Modern Intel Xeons have 1MiB (or 256k on older designs) of private per-core L2 cache.  I don't know enough about the parsec workload to guess which.

Comment: @PeterCordes I truned off HW prefetch then I got the expected result, thanks a lot!